# Lead %%first name%% coming through blank in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a very simple journey set up for testing with the entry source being a new lead in salesforce. The email is sending correctly but the lead first name field is coming through blank. I am probably making an obvious mistake but google and trial and error are failing me. And advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the field name...is it `first name` watch out for caps as the journey builder module uses a case Sensitive Oracle Database? Also check the DE if the field is populating

Comment: Look in your Salesforce Synchronized data extensions.  I would wager a bet that "first name" is the friendly name that appears in your SalesForce account lead record, but the actual field name is `first_name` or a variant of that.

Comment: I tried again with %%First Name%% to see if it was a case sensitive issue but it still came through blank.

Comment: Journey Builder uses the same ol' AMPscript as any other email, which is not case sensitive - so that wouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Journey builder will create a new entry DE and populate with the event data from Salesforce. Have you checked the values on this DE? The field should be called something like Lead:First Name